# error in Blowfish.pm - input must be 8 bytes long

Tags: perl, blowfish

I am trying to encrypt plain text using the Perl's module [`Crypt::Blowfish`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aBlowfish).

My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Crypt::Blowfish;
my $key = pack("H16", "0123456789ABCDEF");
my $cipher = Crypt::Blowfish->new($key);
my $cipher_text = $cipher->encrypt($plain_text);
```

But it returns the error ""input must be 8 bytes long at Crypt/Blowfish.pm"

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Is that your script? What do you have in $plain_text variable?

Comment: I just added a part of my script. The variable $plain_text is the password that we get from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Blowfish, like similar encryption algorithms, encrypts blocks rather than bytes. You need to use something like [Crypt::CBC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Crypt%3a%3aCBC) to provide padding.

Crypt::CBC also provides two other very important functions: salting and chaining. Without these, the encryption is severely weakened.